# Facebook search

Tags: php, facebook

I am new to facebook api. I want to **search** for a particular word on facebook. I have gone through the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/. But I dont know how to construct the query in PHP.

Could any one please provide a sample code. Also how do I specify the **count and page** (like twitter)?

I am currently using the API provided by facebook. I saw that there are alternative API's but I would like to restrict the API to the official one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook provides the search functionality which is like searching using the search inside facebook.com.

To read about it go to here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching

---

## Edit

As it states in that document:

> When searching for public posts or posts on the user's News Feed, you
>   can page over the results by using the since, until and limit
>   parameters. since and until both accept a unix timestamp.

Also, just a bit above the "searching" section there's the "Paging" section, using both you can come up with:

> https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&offset=X&limit=4

Which in terms of using the php sdk, is probably like: "search?q=coffee&type=place&offset=X&limit=4"